# Make page fit all screens

Tags: html, css

I need help with making my HTML fit all screen resolutions. I'd be glad if someone could help, I'll upload root folder. I've tried to make changes but it wont work.

Tried few different resolutions and it works only on 1920x1080 res.

Thanks

```
.html
{
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

#page
{
    z-index: 1;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 585px;
    background-image: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #E6E6E6;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    padding-bottom: 61px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#pu27090
{
    width: 0.01px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    left: -54px;
}

#u27090
{
    z-index: 24;
    width: 217px;
    margin-left: 52px;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshowu5115
{
    z-index: 2;
    width: 0.01px;
    height: 412px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    position: relative;
}

#u5142
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
    background-color: transparent;
    left: 38px;
}

#u5142popup
{
    z-index: 3;
}

#u5143
{
    z-index: 4;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    position: relative;
}

#u5190
{
    z-index: 6;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    position: relative;
}

#u13904
{
    z-index: 8;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    position: relative;
}

#u5208
{
    z-index: 10;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    position: relative;
}

#u5217
{
    z-index: 12;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    position: relative;
}

#u5226
{
    z-index: 14;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    position: relative;
}

#u5235
{
    z-index: 16;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    position: relative;
}

#u5143_clip,#u5190_clip,#u13904_clip,#u5208_clip,#u5217_clip,#u5226_clip,#u5235_clip
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 412px;
}

#u5143_img,#u5190_img,#u13904_img,#u5208_img,#u5217_img,#u5226_img,#u5235_img
{
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-right: -3px;
}

#u5139-3
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    min-height: 20px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999999;
    font-family: Georgia, Palatino, Palatino Linotype, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
    top: 173px;
    background: transparent url("../images/levo.png") no-repeat left top;
}

#u5139-3popup
{
    z-index: 18;
}

#u5135-3
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    min-height: 20px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999999;
    font-family: Georgia, Palatino, Palatino Linotype, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
    top: 173px;
    left: 1073px;
    background: transparent url("../images/desno.png") no-repeat left top;
}

#u5135-3popup
{
    z-index: 21;
}

.SSSlideLoading /* slideshowFreeStyle */
{
    background: url("../images/loading.gif") no-repeat center center;
}

#menuu27092
{
    z-index: 26;
    width: 585px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    margin-top: 62px;
    left: 230px;
}

#u27093
{
    width: 130px;
    min-height: 31px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
}

#u27096
{
    width: 130px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    position: relative;
}

#u27096.MuseMenuActive
{
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    margin: 0px;
    background: transparent url("../images/kvacicaa.png") no-repeat left top;
}

#u27098-4
{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    top: 6px;
    left: 44px;
}

#u27098-4_clip
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 42px;
    height: 17px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#u27098-4_img
{
    display: block;
}

#u27127
{
    width: 161px;
    min-height: 31px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    left: 132px;
}

#u27128
{
    width: 161px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    position: relative;
}

#u27128:hover
{
    margin: 0px;
    background: transparent url("../images/kvacicaa.png") no-repeat left top;
}

#u27130
{
    height: 17px;
    width: 73px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: url("../images/u27130.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    top: 6px;
    left: 44px;
}

#u27128.MuseMenuActive #u27130
{
    background: url("../images/u27130-a.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

#u27120
{
    width: 135px;
    min-height: 31px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    left: 295px;
}

#u27123
{
    width: 135px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    position: relative;
}

#u27128:active,#u27123:hover
{
    margin: 0px;
    background: transparent url("../images/kvacicaa.png") no-repeat left top;
}

#u27124
{
    height: 17px;
    width: 48px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: url("../images/u27124.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    top: 6px;
    left: 43px;
}

#u27123.MuseMenuActive #u27124
{
    background: url("../images/u27124-a.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

#u27113
{
    width: 153px;
    min-height: 31px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    left: 432px;
}

#u27116
{
    width: 153px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    position: relative;
}

#u27123:active,#u27116:hover
{
    margin: 0px;
    background: transparent url("../images/kvacicaa.png") no-repeat left top;
}

#u27116:active
{
    margin: 0px;
    background: transparent url("../images/kvacicaa.png") no-repeat left top;
}

#u27117
{
    height: 17px;
    width: 65px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: url("../images/u27117.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -10000px;
    top: 6px;
    left: 44px;
}

#u27116.MuseMenuActive #u27117
{
    background: url("../images/u27117-a.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.SSFirstButton,.SSPreviousButton,.SSNextButton,.SSLastButton,.SSSlideLink,.SSCloseButton,.MenuItem /* slideshowFreeStyle */
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

body
{
    padding-top: 35px;
}

#page .verticalspacer
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: **Too broad**: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: It's quite rough to diagnose your problem as-is. Maybe you should post a fiddle somewhere, some bits of HTML, and just keep the minimal parts of the CSS needed to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to make it fit in all the screen sizes. always use media queries. 
Something like this will easy for you. its clean and simple

```
/* Tablet Landscape */
@media screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
    #primary { width:67%; }
    #secondary { width:30%; margin-left:3%;}  
}

/* Tabled Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #primary { width:100%; }
    #secondary { width:100%; margin:0; border:none; }
}
```

Comment: how can I implement that into a code? im new with media queries >_<

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make your page fit all screens would be to use media queries which set specific rules depending on the width of the screen. Media queries are the magic behind responsive website design. I would suggest ready more about media queries and also you can use the query template below.

```
// Small screens
@media only screen { } /* Define mobile styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { } /* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use    when QAing mobile issues */

// Medium screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { } /* min-width 641px, medium screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) { } /* min-width 641px and max-width 1024px, use when QAing tablet-only issues */

// Large screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) { } /* min-width 1025px, large screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) and (max-width: 90em) { } /* min-width        1025px and max-width 1440px, use when QAing large screen-only issues */

// XLarge screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) { } /* min-width 1441px, xlarge screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) and (max-width: 120em) { } /* min-width     1441px and max-width 1920px, use when QAing xlarge screen-only issues */

// XXLarge screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) { } /* min-width 1921px, xlarge screens */
```